# Regex for = followed by any string followed by & in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

So I want to replace all the sequences of  = (followed by any sequence of letters and other characters) &

This is in Java.

I am thinking of using

```
originalString.replaceAll(regex, stringReplacement)
```

I got the problem now. The `replaceAll` method is replacing the string like this:

if original string is

```
username = dka & password = hoho & id= 9283 & pid = 3784;
```

the statement `replaceAll("=.*&", "=HELLO&")` gives:

```
username =HELLO& pid = 3784
```

What I want is

```
username =HELLO& password =HELLO& id =HELLO& pid = 3784;
```

The `replaceAll` doesn't seem to work

Comment: you want to replace everything until the & right?

Comment: Can you show something you've tried?

Comment: @user432 Yes everything beginning from = till the &.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I tried url.replaceAll("=.*&","=HELLOOO&" ). This only replaces the first occurence but I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: Seems fine to me. Have you tested it?

Comment: @Rogue Can you look at the edited question. I stated my problem little more clearly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex wildcard match is using a greedy-search. Make it non-greedy by appending `?` to it, so that it matches as few characters as possible:

```
String test = " username = dka & password = hoho & id= 9283 & pid = 3784; ";
System.out.println(test.replaceAll("=.*?&", "=HELLO&"));
//prints out: ' username =HELLO& password =HELLO& id=HELLO& pid = 3784; '
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! No idea about the greedy search.I dont use regex a lot.

Comment: If thee pairs are URL-style, a better approach is to match ```"=[^&]*"```. It's more robust in the event a trailing ampersand is omitted.